# Две сетевые карты на Debian Linux с активацией только одной

Tags: linux, сеть, debian, network-manager

В общем такой вопрос, есть сервер, на борту Linux Debian 11. Есть два сетевых интерфейса. Задача состоит в том, чтобы работал только один интерфейс, а второй был потушен. Но в нужное время, желательном скриптом, тушить активный интерфейс и запускать тот который был не активный. Так же если сервер перезагрузить или если он сам вырубиться, то при запуске активировался только тот интерфейс, который был активным до перезапуска. Есть ли возможность такое реализовать?

Comment: Ну минимум `ifconfig eth1 down` точно должен работать.

Answer (score 0):

Например enp0s8 и enp0s9, тогда в файле `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto enp0s8
allow-hotplug enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
  metric 10

iface enp0s9 inet dhcp
  mrtric 20
```

Метрика чтоб основной маршрут не перезаписывался - можешь потерять его вообще в некоторых настройках без этого. Да и метрикой можно менять шлюз не роняя интерфейс. У первого allow-hotplug и auto - запуск при загрузке.

Поднять второй `ifup enp0s9`, опустить первый `ifdown enp0s8`

Подробнее о настройки статики и днс https://wiki.debian.org/ru/NetworkConfiguration и [https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/настройка_сети_вручную](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E)